# Strange std::wregex behavior

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I've been stuck on this strange std:wregex behavior :

```
^(?:(?:[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*\\w+[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*:/)|(?:\\./))(?:(?:[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*\\w+[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*/?)|(?:\\./)|(?:\\.\\./))*$
```

raise an exception with

```
e.code() == regex_constants::error_brack
```

The weird thing is that i've been testing it with an online ECMAScript regex validator without any troubles. Plus de fact that removing the first pair of brackets as follow.

```
^(?:(?:\\w+[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*:/)|(?:\\./))(?:(?:[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*\\w+[^\\u0000-\\u001f<>:\\\\\"/\\\\\\|\\?\\*]*/?)|(?:\\./)|(?:\\.\\./))*$
```

Actually solves the problem, without any particular regard to bracket mismatch.

Any one has an explanation to that kind of behavior ?

EDIT:

Seems that even L"[^\u0000-\u001f]" doesn't work.

EDIT:

I'm running a sample on compile and execute, didn't notice that it used GCC. Plus the fact that MVSC seems to be when GCC is giving me a runtime error (exception).

Comment: Not that this would break the pattern, but why does your character class, contain two literal backslashes? (`\\\\ `... before `"` and after `/`)

Comment: The regex is formated so it's suitable in c code. So \\\\ is in fact \\ as plain regex. The 1st and 3rd are escape sequences for c and the 2nd is escape sequence for regex.

Comment: I know that four backslashes make one literal backslash in the pattern, but you've got four backslashes twice in the same character class. Replacing the backslashes with `b`, that's like writing `[^...<>:b\"/b\\|...]`.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, attempting to use GNU libstdc++? It does not yet support regular expressions (even though some of them compile). I am able to reproduce your error with it, but not with LLVM libc++ or with boost.regex

Comment: What do you mean by the last edit? You mention an exception when using gcc. <regex> will not work on gcc, the library is not fully implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is really old however someone may benefit from an answer.

The issue is the `null` in the regex string `\u0000`, which the compiler will interpret as the end of the string.

Regex strings should be declared raw, for example `R"(some regex string)"`. 
This will solve any `null` issues in your regex.